# How to get a ZonedDateTime from unix time on API level 16?

Tags: android, unix-timestamp, zoneddatetime

I have to do some date manipulations [*cringe*] and I am trying to use ZonedDateTime for all its neat methods. My timestamp is in Unix time (epoch), and my API level is 16, how do I go about it?

For those using API 26+, the ZonedDateTime can be initiated using the class Instant, as such:

```
long timestamp = 1234567890;
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp);
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(i, ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: I am guessing this won't be possible from reading the doc... grrrr... Calendar class it is.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a third-party library, such as [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) from the indefatigable Jake Wharton.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I am going to try to use the Calendar class before I do that. It would have been much simpler if we had 13 months of 4 weeks with 7 days and a day to kill.